# How can I get external jar exception in java spring?

Tags: java, spring, exception, twain

I have spring boot application which runs the scanner and get the output of scanner. To do that I used `uk.co.mmscomputing.device` with the external jar.
However when a usb cable is not pluged in or when selected device is not avaiable it throws an `Exception`. I need to know when an `Exception` is thrown and handle it.
How can I do that ?

Here is my code

```java
public class TwainExample implements ScannerListener{

  static TwainExample app;  

  Scanner scanner;

  public TwainExample(String[] argv)throws ScannerIOException{
    scanner=Scanner.getDevice();
    scanner.addListener(this);    
    scanner.acquire();
  }

  public void update(ScannerIOMetadata.Type type, ScannerIOMetadata metadata){
    if(type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.ACQUIRED)){
      BufferedImage image=metadata.getImage();
      System.out.println("Have an image now!");
      try{
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("mmsc_image.png"));
      }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }else if(type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.NEGOTIATE)){
      ScannerDevice device=metadata.getDevice();
      try{
//        device.setShowUserInterface(true);
//        device.setShowProgressBar(true);
//        device.setResolution(100);
      }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }else if(type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.STATECHANGE)){
      System.err.println(metadata.getStateStr());
      if(metadata.isFinished()){
        System.exit(0);
      }
    }else if(type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.EXCEPTION)){
      metadata.getException().printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] argv){
    try{
      app=new TwainExample(argv);
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: right now all your `try`-`catch` blocks are using `Exception` - can you see the exception being thrown in the console/log? if so, add a `catch(SomeException){...}` block above your `catch(Exception){...}` block and handle it there. if you can't see the Exceptions in their docs, you could use a decompiler like **jd-gui** and decompile and search for all classes called something like `SomethingException` and add catch blocks for those...

Comment: jar throw the exception, I can see it in the console, however it comes from jar, ı cannot get the origin, ı dont have the source code. when it throw exception I need to do some operations.

Comment: if you are  using a java class from the .jar file you CAN follow the steps I wrote and get the error. The reason the error is on the console is that you are printing it using `catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
      }` ... `catch(Exception e)` catches ALL exceptions read https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1148